# MVC render name of the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

We have some pages (lets call it parent pages) that calls to other .aspx (lets call it child pages) using RenderAction.

What i would like to do is use in these parent pages some kind of helper that prints the name of these child pages if in the querystring appears debug=1 using something like:

```
@Html.AutodiscoverWidgets()
```

Its possible to do this? I would like to avoid put in every child page something like:

```
@Html.AutodiscoverWidgets("NameOfTheChildView")
```

What i have by the moment is the following extension method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString AutodiscoverWidgets(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
      if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["debug"].ToString() == "1")
      {

                return MvcHtmlString.Create("hello");
      }
      else
      {
                return MvcHtmlString.Create("");
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CurrentViewName(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    var view = htmlHelper.ViewContext.View as BuildManagerCompiledView;
    if (view != null)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(view.ViewPath);
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.CurrentViewName()
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if its possible to render too the controller action name responsable to render the view? Best Regards.

Comment: @Jose3d, you could use `htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller")` and `htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")`.